# Links not working (HTML5/CSS)

Tags: css, html

Note: I am a beginner.  For some reason, my links that were working don't work at all anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfoliostyles.css">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header"><a href="home.html"><img class="hoofd" src="images/leaugeau.png" alt="logo"></a>  
        <ul>
           <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <img class="line" src="images/line.jpg" alt="lijn" width='95%' height='2px'>

    <div class=content>
       <img class="image" src="images/thumbnails/watrgatrthumb.jpg" alt="watrgatr" width=400px height=400px>
       <img class="image" src="images/thumbnails/typhlotrainerthumb.jpg" alt="watrgatr" width=400px height=400px>
       <img class="image" src="images/thumbnails/anneketrainerthumb.jpg" alt="watrgatr" width=400px height=400px>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html,body
{
        height: 150%;
        width: 100%;
        margin:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.hoofd
{
        float:  left;
        margin:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.header
{
        height: 216px;
        width: 99%;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.line
{
        margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
        padding-top: 216px;
        position:fixed;
}

ul
{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin-right:5%;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;     
}

li
{
        display:inline;
        float:right;
        margin-right:2%;
        font-size:45px;
        line-height: 280px;

}

.content
{
        padding: 230px 0 0 1.5%;
}

a
{
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-light";
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
}


a:hover
{
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-light";
        color: #E8DA62;
}

h1
{
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-thin";
        font-size:      24px;
}

p
{
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-thin";


 font-size: 12px;
}
```

edit: Oh, and to clarify: My pages where, indeed, in the root folder, so no more folder-linking necessary.

But it got solved, thanks! Gotta work something out for the fixed line thing though. But it'll work out.

Comment: Where is your home.html, contact.html and about.html? Is it in same folder?

Comment: You need to make sure that your links (contact.html and about.html, for example) are in the same directory as this Home HTML file.

Comment: In addition to checking your link locations, also check your HTML for easily missed mistakes. http://validator.w3.org

Comment: I suggest you use editor like webstorm, so you will get notice/highlighted if you have invalid link or code on your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with the CSS code is you are using `fixed` position on some `classes`.

would be better if you remove `position: fixed;` from below these  two classes.

For better understanding check the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/nexaxequ/1/).

```
.header
{
    height: 216px;
    width: 99%;
    position: fixed; /*Remove this line; so anchor tag could work*/
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.line
{
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    padding-top: 216px;
    position:fixed;/*Remove this line; so anchor tag could work*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overlapping with `position:fixed`

remove it from

```
.line
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nJ8G8/)

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to see without an actual example, but it looks like your `.line` is on top of them. If I'm correct:

Since it's `position:fixed`, it is being overlayed at the top, then you have given it a `padding-top:216px;` which is increasing the area it is consuming from the top, likely overlaying itself ontop of your header and navigation menu.

To fix it, you should figure out another way to position `.line` wherever you are trying to. You likely want `top:216`:

```
.line {
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    top: 216px;
    position:fixed;
}
```